# How to make button visible in video view "OnPreparedListener" method

Tags: android, button, android-videoview

I have play button and videoview in my activity. In xml, I made the button as invisible. In java code I'm try to make it visible.

In video view's `OnPreparedListener` method I'm trying to make it visible. but its not getting visible. below is my code.

```
        vvVideos.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnPlay.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

**XML File ::**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. If you've found a solution, post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this ::

```
 vvVideos.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnPlay.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Use this and Try ::

```
 vvVideos.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That also i tried it didnt work, i found the solution, its updated in my question....